# Downvote on answer in multiple-tagged question is counted more than once?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

I answered a question over on Gaming - and got a downvote (fair enough - it was a wrong answer in the end).

But, it appears that the single downvote has been counted twice against my reputation - once for each tag the question was tagged with.

Is this a bug or a feature of the SE engine? Does this mean upvotes are also counted more than once? (Although, that has not been my experience so far)

Update:
Screenshot from my user profile:

[image]

Comment: What's that floaty box repu-charge click clack thing show?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [your reputation page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7185/horuskol?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time), you got downvoted on one answer. A downvote leads to a reputation loss of 2, which is what happened for you.

You have two `-1`s next to the `wii` and `wii-sports` tags there because you got downvoted once in each tag. It just so happens that they were for the same question.

The numbers next to the tags are for discrete votes, not reputation change. If you got up-voted, you'd see a `1` in the respective tag, but you'd gain 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't count against you twice.

A downvote cost 1 reputation to give, but the penalty to the poster is -2 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The `-1` next to the Answer list represents the `NET vote count`, which is not the `net REP change` (+10/-2).

---

There is only one down-vote in your reputation page:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7185/horuskol?tab=reputation

```
-2 / downvote / How do I serve a fast ball in Wii Sports?
```

- It costs -1 for **you**  to down-vote someone else.
- It costs -2 when **someone else** down-votes you.

Read the FAQ once in a while.. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq

> ### What is reputation?
>
> ...
>   post is voted down     -2  (-1 to voter)

Comment: Downvoting a downvote explanation is like bootstrapping a boot.